# Multiplication table function won't append properly

Tags: python, for-loop, append, nested-for-loop

I want the multiplication function to return this when n = 4:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 4, 6, 8],
 [3, 6, 9, 12],
 [4, 8, 12, 16]]
```

Code:

```
import numpy

def multiplication_table(n): 
    full_multi = [[]] * n 

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            full_multi[i].append( (i+1)*(j+1) )

    list_as_array = numpy.array(full_multi)

    return list_as_array
print(multiplication_table(4))
```

Instead, this is returned(ignore the format):

```
[

[ 1  2  3  4  2  4  6  8  3  6  9 12  4  8 12 16]

[ 1  2  3  4  2  4  6  8  3  6  9 12  4  8 12 16]

[ 1  2  3  4  2  4  6  8  3  6  9 12  4  8 12 16]

[ 1  2  3  4  2  4  6  8  3  6  9 12  4  8 12 16]

]
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. Thx for any help!

Comment: `full_multi = [[]] * n ` this doesnt do what you think. Try `full_multi = [[] for _ in range(n)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `[[] * n]` to `[[] for _ n range(n)]`  like this:

```py
import numpy

def multiplication_table(n): 
    full_multi = [[] for _ n range(n)] 

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            full_multi[i].append((i+1)*(j+1))

    list_as_array = numpy.array(full_multi)

    return list_as_array
print(multiplication_table(4))
```

This outputs the desired

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 4, 6, 8],
 [3, 6, 9, 12],
 [4, 8, 12, 16]]
```

The reason the 2 codes are different is because of how copying (in this case multiplying lists) works. By doing `[[] * n]`, you don't actually create `n` different lists but simply create `n` references of the `[]` list.

If we debug the code by adding a `print` statement after `full_multi[i].append( (i+1)*(j+1))` to print the value of `full_multi` we can see this behavior:

```py
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
...
```

Adding a value to the first list also makes it appear in the rest because they all reference the same data. However, the `for` loop method actually creates `n` separate lists.

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/ for more.

When copying lists (or any non-primitive data type) in Python (or most languages), you don't actually duplicate the data but simply create a new reference.

```py
a = 5
b = a  # for primitive data like integers, the value 5 is copied over
```

```py
a = []
b = a  # only the reference to the list stored in 'a' is copied

a.append(5)
print(a, b)  # will both be the same value since they are the same list, just referenced by 2 different variables
```

If you'd like to actually copy the list itself, you must do something like:

```py
a = []
b = a.copy()  # copies the list, not just the reference

a.append(5)
print(a, b)  # will both be different
```

Comment: Thx for the full info and help! I understand now. I did not know that I actually created n references of the [] list. I thought by multiplying I would get n amount of lists, but it does not work like that I reckon now. Also, thx for the source and explanation on how copy/assignment in python works.

Comment: glad I could help :)